# Splitting a String, from an input File with char and ints

Tags: java

I'm trying to split some input code from a file a certain way and am completely lost on how to do it. I have the file reading incorrectly. I'm just not sure how to split it the way I want it. I currently have it set up like this (below) and it works fine I'm just wondering if there's a way to split it again or something, the lines from the file look as followed:
**"Y8 T  L6 L2 T Y3"** the numbers or letters could vary, and might or might not have a number, I would set it up so I can have every character and number separated into their own String[], how can I do this? the way I have it set up now takes the number along with the character and I don't want that as I need access to the numerical values, thanks.

Code

```
{
    File file = new File(FileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] seperated = currentLine.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looping over your result and testing the characters for whether they're letters or numbers and possibly constructing a new list?  This might help for tests: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea

Comment: how is it a bad idea? its what i need to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed continue with what you have. Since you've read everything in and separated it into a String array, you can loop over the elements in the array and check to see if they have a number following them. The code I'm going to post assumes that each input is either 1) a single letter or 2) a single letter followed by a single number:

```
for (String temp : seperated) {
    int numberIWant;
    if (temp.length() == 2) {
        numberIWant = temp.charAt(1);
    }
    //Do something with this number, if you need the letter as well
    //Use temp.charAt(0)
```

Comment: @BryanWheatfield sorry, don't mean to kick a dead horse. Would you mind upvoting or marking as top if it did what you needed it to?

Answer (score 0):

If your interest is just having the two separate arrays, then you may not need to split. Just remove the white space and separate the numbers from the other characters.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String currentLine = "Y8 T L6 L2 T Y3";
        //Remove the spaces
        String withoutSpaces = currentLine.replace(" ", "");
        String[] characters = withoutSpaces.split("");
        List<Integer> numeric = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> character = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String each : characters) {
            if (isNum(each)) {
                numeric.add(Integer.parseInt(each));
            } else {
                character.add(each);
            }
        }
        Integer[] numarray = numeric.toArray(new Integer[numeric.size()]);
        String[] chararray = character.toArray(new String[character.size()]);

        for(Integer num: numarray){
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        for(String charac: chararray){
            System.out.println(charac);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isNum(String strNum) {
        boolean ret = true;
        try {

            Double.parseDouble(strNum);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```